# Using this.title to retrieve an image title

Tags: javascript

I apologize if this seems to be a stupid or overly simple question, but I have been given an assignment that tasks us with changing the TITLE of an image using an OnClick handler. Thus far, I've been able to change the title of the image, but the assignment also requires us to utilize this.title in order to access the original title of the image.

I've tried quite a lot thus far, and have only come back with "undefined" as the title. Here is my code copy and pasted below. I would really appreciate any help!

This is what I used to try to get the original title of the image:

```html
<img id="image" src="https://bb9.canyons.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-692768-dt-content-rid-9288981_1/courses/2015SU-CMPSCI190-16424/tick.gif" alt="tick" onclick="getValue()" />

<script>
  function getValue() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image').title;
    alert(x.innerHTML)
  }
</script>
```

And this is what I want to use to try to change the title of the image:

```
<img src ="https://bb9.canyons.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-692768-dt-content-rid-9288981_1/courses/2015SU-CMPSCI190-16424/tick.gif" title="insert original image title here" onclick="this.title='My New Title';"/>
```

Comment: According to your example, your image originally has no title attribute.

Comment: *"but the assignment also requires us to utilize this.title in order to access the original title of the image."* I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Why are you doing `x.innerHTML`?  `x` is not an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is quite correct, the only problem is that you are trying to call innerHTML on a string (the title). Maybe try something like:

```
function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('image').title = "NEW TITLE";
}
```

if you want to change the value or just

```
function getValue() {
    var x = document.getElementById('image').title;
    alert(x);
}
```

to show the title value